# How to release all CLLocationManager instances when i click on logout button in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, cllocationmanager

My app is a tab bar. i have 4 views and i have CLLocationManager instance in every view. In every view i have logout button. I want to release all CLLocationManager instances when i click on logout. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to fire off a notification when the user hits logout and listen for it in each of the classes that have a `CLLocationManager` then do the logic for tearing it down.

Comment: but when  i press logout then application doesn't go to background mode?

Comment: Thanks buddy. I never used Notification before. Its working perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

as a different solution why not have a singleton `CLLocationManager` attached to the delegate (or static shared manager on some `CustomLocationManager` class)? It seems a waste to have 4 location managers with only one user...

you can then release it with the same code from each logout button